# Converting Lightweight AP to Autonomous AP

Tags: cisco, wireless

I need help from someone who already tried to convert a lightweight Cisco Aironet 1700 AP to an autonomous AP. I tried to do that, but I couldn't access it, even with the console port

I have tried to telnet to it, but Cisco requires a password to be reset before we can telnet to the device. I tried the console cable, but it kept giving me a blank page.

Comment: You will need to provide some more detail in your question, such as the model and what you have done that doesn't work.

Comment: aironet 1700 AP, I have tried to telnet it but in vain because cisco requires a password to be reset before we can telnet the device, tried the console cable but it kept giving me a blank page !

Comment: i have the IOS image on the laptop but i can't connect the AP to the laptop, there is not ethernet interface on the AP

Comment: An AP without an Ethernet interface wouldn't be of much use, would it?  See http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1700/quick/guide/ap1700getstart.html#31481

Comment: [Cisco Aironet Access Points IOS Recovery](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/31571/cisco-aironet-access-points-ios-recovery)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you download the autonomous IOS to the AP via TFTP? This will have to be done first to get the correct software onto the AP. Look for the "w8" think "light'w8'" in the file name. More info here: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/8-0/configuration-guide/b_cg80/b_cg80_chapter_01101010.html#ID1136

Answer (score 1):

Use the [mode button](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/15_2_4_JB/configuration/guide/scg15-2-4-Book/scg15-2-4-chap4-first.html#96723) to reset it to factory defaults